# PROLOG: Keep list in recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, key-pair

So, I've spent a lot of my time trying to figure this out without almost no progress. Hope you could help me.
The goal is, to take a list like this(lets call it baselist): `[[[feesc,11],[podshare,11]],[[feesc,11]],[]]. And make it become this: [[feesc,22],[podshare,11]]`.

I have a predicate responsible to add or sum to the resulting list. Here is the code:

```
place_key([Key,Value], [], [Key,Value]).
place_key([Key,Value], [[Key,V]|Rest], [[Key,V1]|Rest]) :- V1 is V+Value.
place_key([Key,Value], [[K,V]|Rest], [[K,V]|List2]) :- Key \= K, place_key([Key,Value], Rest, List2)."
```

If I manually call this method, for simulating the recursion, it works exactly how I want.
Example:

```
 place_key([feesc,11], [], R), place_key([feesc,11],R,J). 
So J is = [[feesc,22]].
```

Expected result is correct.
The problem is to that with recursion.

So basically what I need to do is: iterate through the baselist, when reaching each key/par list, call place_key and keep it in the stack so the recursion keeps it until the last. 
Just to point out, I don't want to append, I just need the latest result from place_key.

What I have done so far:

```
fe([HO|T],NL,R) :- write(HO), place_key(HO,NL,RESULT), fe(T,RESULT,R).
fe(S,R):- fe(S,[],R).
fe([],[]).
feg([HO,T],R) :- fe(HO,RESULT), feg(T,RESULT), R = RESULT.
feg([],[]).
```

When I run:

```
[trace] 57 ?- feg([[[feesc,11]],[[feesc,11]]],R).
   Call: (6) feg([[[feesc, 11]], [[feesc, 11]]], _G21384) ? creep
   Call: (7) fe([[feesc, 11]], _G21484) ? creep
   Call: (8) fe([[feesc, 11]], [], _G21485) ? creep
   Call: (9) place_key([feesc, 11], [], _G21485) ? creep
   Exit: (9) place_key([feesc, 11], [], [[feesc, 11]]) ? creep //Until here, I think this is correct.
   Call: (9) fe([], [[feesc, 11]], _G21494) ? creep 
   Fail: (9) fe([], [[feesc, 11]], _G21494) ? creep
   Redo: (9) place_key([feesc, 11], [], _G21485) ? creep
   Fail: (9) place_key([feesc, 11], [], _G21485) ? creep
   Fail: (8) fe([[feesc, 11]], [], _G21485) ? creep
   Fail: (7) fe([[feesc, 11]], _G21484) ? creep
   Fail: (6) feg([[[feesc, 11]], [[feesc, 11]]], _G21384) ? creep
false.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, feg means, for experience group, and fe means for experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you don't define a base-case for `fe/3`. As you can see, except for your place_key predicate, you also have the following:

```
fe([HO|T],NL,R) :- write(HO), place_key(HO,NL,RESULT), fe(T,RESULT,R).
fe(S,R):- fe(S,[],R).
fe([],[]).
feg([HO,T],R) :- fe(HO,RESULT), feg(T,RESULT), R = RESULT.
feg([],[]).
```

I'll try to make this a little more readable, so you can see what's going on:

```
% fe/3 cases
fe([Head|Tail],Current,Result) :- write(Head), place_key(Head,Current,TempResult), fe(Tail,TempResult,Result).
% fe/2 cases
fe(S,R):- fe(S,[],R).
fe([],[]).
%% this case above is never used, as the first case always matches
% recursive and base cases for feg
feg([HO,T],R) :- fe(HO,RESULT), feg(T,RESULT), R = RESULT.
feg([],[]).
```

You should rewrite this as following:

```
fe([],Result,Result).
```

This is your base case, if the list is empty, the result in-between is equal to the final result. Prolog always tries the first possible match first, so always set your base-case on top.

```
fe([Head|Tail],Current,Result) :- write(Head), place_key(Head,Current,TempResult), fe(Tail,TempResult,Result).
```

This is your recursive case, as you had before, which we will put below our base case.

We can drop the second `fe/2` case, as the first case always matches and we rewrite to `fe/3` anyway, which can handle all cases.

```
fe(S,R):- fe(S,[],R).
```

Below are your existing `feg/2` cases. Here is also an error, because after your first `fe/2`-predicate, the RESULT-variable has a value, but it still needs to be able to unify with the call `feq(T,RESULT)`, which will produce a different value. I'll leave this as an exercise.

```
feg([HO,T],R) :- fe(HO,RESULT), feg(T,RESULT), R = RESULT.
feg([],[]).
```

Comment: OMG @Snicksie! Thx man, now I got it. Thanks for leaving the exercise as well, helped me understand better. The final code:
fe([Head|Tail],Current,Result) :- place_key(Head,Current,TempResult), fe(Tail,TempResult,Result).
fe([],Result,Result). 
feg([Head|Tail],Current,Result) :- fe(Head,Current,TempResult), feg(Tail,TempResult,Result).
feg([],Result,Result). 
feg(S,R):- feg(S,[],R).

Answer (score 0):

Keep your key/pairs as a *tuple*, a simple term with an arity of 2. Something like `K-V` or `K:V` or even `tuple(K,V)` is preferable to `[K,V]`. There's a simple reason for this:

- `K-V`, `K:V` and `tuple(K,V)` all map to simple structures: `-(K,V)`, `:(K,V)` and `tuple(K,V)` respectively, while...
- `[K,V]` is syntactic sugar for a rather more complicated structure `.(K,.(V,[]))`.

Further, you might realize that your key/value pairs are hard to distinguish from the nested list-of-lists. Keeping the Key/Value pairs as tuples makes that distincation clear.

So, let us assume your key/value pairs are represented as `K:V`. It sounds to me that what you're essentially wanting to do is walk your nested list-of-lists (essentially, a tree), enumerate the key/value pairs it contains and produce the *set* (unique). Here's one way to do that.

First, a simple predicate to identify a non-empty list:

```
nonnempty_list( L ) :- nonvar(L) , L = [_|_] .
```

Then, a simple predicate to walk the nested list of lists and enumerate each key/value pair it finds:

```
visit( [ K:R | Ls ] , K:R ) . % succeed if the head of the list is a key/value pair.
visit( [ L | Ls ] , KVP ) :-  % otherwise...
  nonempty_list(L) ,          % - if the head is a non-empty list ,
  visit( L , KVP )            % - visit it.
  .                           %
visit( [_|Ls] , KVP ) :-      % finally...
  visit( Ls , KVP )           % - recurse down on the tail.
  .                           %
```

Then you can use the magic of `setof/3` to get what you want:

```
flattened_set( LoL , KVPs ) :-
  setof( KVP , visit(LoL,KVP) , KVPs )
  .
```